# Reduce the number of parameters in ML model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, data-science

I want to train the AWS xgBoost model for classification into two categories based on my dataset which contains 1000 Emails and the value to predict. Ex data -

- abc@gmail -- high
- 123@yahoo -- low
- xyz@gmail -- low
- jkl@yahoo -- high

For training the model on 1000 rows of such data, as xgboost only expects numerical data, I had to use pd.getDummies() which converts this into 1000 columns by 1000 rows of data. Converts the result column into two - isHigh, isLow with values 0 and 1.

Now when I want predictions from my model, it expects an input of 1000 parameters for the REST API(which I created for predictions), ideally, I would like to provide an email as the parameter and get a result of high/low or isHigh value between 0 and 1.

Is the choice of Algorithm wrong?
Is there any other way so that when I ask the model to provide predictions it does not want 100 parameters?

Comment: You want to predict something as low or high based on email addresses? I have a feeling that this does not make much sense, as there isn't much useful information in such short sequence of text. But let's assume you have email content and want to detect spam. Then you would need some way to transform your email content into a vector representation like word embeddings. For a simple start you could try something like one hot encoding, but this does not encode any semantic so you should familiarize yourself with works like BERT etc. and how they do embeddings.

Comment: @RenéJahn Thanks for the insights.

The direction that I am looking for is that when we have a lot of unique values like email addresses that leads to a lot of columns in the training data for the model. 

Which later leads to a lot of parameters for hitting the model through an API to get a prediction, I want a direction to reduce the number of parameters in the API call which makes the prediction